# Google Groups "Spam message handling" Setting Won't Stay Set

Tags: google-groups

I have a free Google Groups group setup and messages (which are being forwarded from a Gmail account) keep going into the Pending moderation queue. I've repeatedly attempted to change the "Spam message handling" setting (only visible when you click "Advanced settings") to "Post suspicious messages to the group", but every time I refresh the settings page it's reverted back to "Moderate and notify content moderators".

Is there a way to actually change this setting and allow these messages through?